# Média não está sendo armazenada-C

Tags: c, arquivo, struct

Boa noite!

Ao rodar o programa e informar os dados Nome, Nota1 e Nota2, é esperado que o programa crie um arquivo chamado "turma.txt" com o nome do aluno, notas e a média.

Contudo meu problema está em ler a média corretamente, ao abrir o txt, a média está sempre igual a 0.00. Queria saber como corrigir esse erro.

Obrigado.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct
{
    char nome[50];
    float nota1, nota2,media;

}aluno [10];



int main()
{
FILE *arq;
int j;
float media;

    for(j=0; j<10; j++)
    {
        printf("\n \t Dados do aluno %d", j+1);

        printf("\n\n Nome: ");
        scanf("%s", aluno[j].nome);
        fflush(stdin);

        printf("\n Nota 1: ");
        scanf ("%f", &aluno[j].nota1);

        printf("\n Nota 2: ");
        scanf ("%f", &aluno[j].nota2);
    }

    for (j=0; j<10; j++);
    {
        aluno[j].media=((aluno[j].nota1)+(aluno[j].nota2))/2;

    }
    printf("\n\n");
    printf("\t Calculando medias e criando arquivo.....");
    printf("\n");


    arq = fopen("turma.txt","w");

    for (j=0; j<10; j++)
    {

        fprintf(arq,"\n \t Dados do aluno %d \n", j+1);

        fprintf(arq,"\n\n Nome: %s, ",aluno[j].nome);

        fprintf(arq,"%.2f, ", aluno[j].nota1);

        fprintf(arq,"%.2f; ", aluno[j].nota2);

        fprintf(arq,"%.2f \n", aluno[j].media);

    }
    fclose(arq);
    system("cls");
    system("pause");

}
```

Comment: Você já verificou se seu array `aluno` está sendo carregado corretamente? Os nomes dos alunos tem sempre uma única palavra, isto é, sem espaços, como por ex.: `José Roberto`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gustavo, no seu código você está iterando 2 vezes desnecessariamente.

Eu tirei o loop que calcula a média e coloquei dentro do for que faz as leituras das notas.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct {
    char nome[50];
    float nota1, nota2, media;
} aluno[10];

int main() {

    FILE *arq;
    int j; 
    float media;
    int total_aluno = 2; 

    for(j=0; j<total_aluno; j++) {
        printf("\n \t Dados do aluno %d", j+1);

        printf("\n\n Nome: ");
        scanf("%s", &aluno[j].nome);
        fflush(stdin);

        printf("\n Nota 1: ");
        scanf ("%f", &aluno[j].nota1);

        printf("\n Nota 2: ");
        scanf ("%f", &aluno[j].nota2);
        // Calculando as médias aqui 
        aluno[j].media = (aluno[j].nota1 + aluno[j].nota2)/2;
    }

    printf("\n\n");
    printf("\t Calculando medias e criando arquivo.....");
    printf("\n");

    arq = fopen("turma.txt","w");

    for (j=0; j<total_aluno; j++) {

        fprintf(arq,"\n \t Dados do aluno %d \n", j+1);

        fprintf(arq,"\n\n Nome: %s, ",aluno[j].nome);

        fprintf(arq,"%.2f, ", aluno[j].nota1);

        fprintf(arq,"%.2f; ", aluno[j].nota2);

        fprintf(arq,"%.2f \n", aluno[j].media);

    }
    fclose(arq);
    system("cls");
    system("pause");
}
```

Eu achei bem estranho o erro, mas me parece algo com a referência da variável.

Answer (score 0):

Antes do `fclose(arq);` chame o `fflush(arq);`

Comment: Mesmo assim, a média continua aparecendo zerada. O estranho é estar armazenando o valor 0.00 para ela.